# How to find nested array object by mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[
  {
  _id: new ObjectId("63cc22dfe258792490ac0fb5"),
  categoryName: 'Rental Equipment',
  products: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a"),
      partName: 'product one'
      partNumber: 'ym129150-35151'
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("63ce2221207c858d01a3c8ac"),
      partName: 'product two',
      partNumber: 'ym129150-35151',
    }
  ]
},{
  _id: new ObjectId("63cc22dfe258792490ac0fb5"),
  categoryName: 'Engine Parts',
  products: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("23ce9701ba156f972473cd3a"),
      partName: 'product one'
      partNumber: 'ym129150-35151'
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("73ce2221203c858d01a3c83b"),
      partName: 'product two',
      partNumber: 'ym129150-35151',
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I want to find the specific array(products) of object which one is located in the products array. I tried to find out the array of object but it's return a whole collections of object where the products `_id` is located.

```
const product = db.collection.find({
      products: {
        $elemMatch: {
          _id: "63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a",
        },
      },
    });
```

I Want to find a specific object from the products array.

**The output would be:**

```
{
   _id: new ObjectId("63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a"),
   partName: 'product one'
   partNumber: 'ym129150-35151'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "products._id": "63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "products._id": 1,
      "products.partName": 1,
      "products.partNumber": 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$products"
    }
  }
])
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IL3BfvVr_0n) to playground

Comment: It's working in the mongo playground but not in my code may there some another problem, can you please explain these methods?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This is not working when it has a new keyword in the _id, It's Just working when I have just a _id string,

In this way it's not working
{
   _id: new ObjectId("63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a")
}

In this way, it's working
{
   _id: "63ce9701ba256f972473cd6a"
}